# cordova emulate - selecting an Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, cordova

I've got a few AVDs defined for testing on various API levels, 10-19. When I run `cordova emulate android`, it says:

> WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to {ITEM ON THE TOP}

It selects the target AVD at the top of the list, whatever that might be. As a result, I've been deleting all AVDs and re-creating a new one when I need to test a new device. I can't find any flags for `cordova emulate` for selecting an AVD, is there such a flag? Or is there a way to specify a default AVD?

Comment: I found no way to select a default AVD. But it seems cordova will select the first device in alphabetic order. So renaming a AVD was solving the issue to me.

Answer (score 21):

`cordova emulate --target={AVD_NAME} android`.

For some reason I thought that `--target` meant the Android version target (eg, 4.0.3) and would thus create an ad hoc AVD. Don't know why I thought that. But anyway, --target is the name/ID of your AVD.